# Given two point in a 3d space, how can I find the plane that intersect them?

Tags: 3d, intersection, point, arkit, plane

I want to add a plane node to my virtual world in arkit given two points that the user choose previously.

Answer (score 1):

Two points is not enough to define a unique plane. The space shared by two arbitrary points is a line — infinitely many planes could share that line (relating them as an axis of rotation).

If you want to define a plane based on arbitrary user-chosen points, you have a few other options you can explore:

- Have the user pick *three* points instead of two, since three points define a unique plane. Take the cross product of two legs of the triangle formed by those points and you have the normal vector for the plane, which tells you its orientation.
- Select two points, then assume that out of all the possible planes connecting those points, the user wants a certain one — say, one whose normal vector is closest to vertical. (A few more cross products might help here.)
- Assume the user wants a plane that is horizontal (parallel to the x-z plane). For a horizontal plane, you need only one user-placed point.

---

Proceeding from the clarification that you’re looking for a vertical plane:

1. Subtract the two points to get the line segment between them: `let segment = pointA - pointB` or simliar
2. Take the cross product of that vector and the vertical axis to get the normal vector of the vertical plane they both lie in: `let normal = cross(segment, float3(0,1,0))`
3. A normal vector defines the orientation of a plane, but you probably want a quaternion or a transform matrix so you can use that orientation with SceneKit. There’s a quaternion initializer that gives you the rotation from one basis vector to another, so the orientation of your vertical plane can be based on the rotation from vertical to your calculated normal: something like `node.simdOrientation = simd_quatf(from: float3(0,1,0), to: normal)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I should have been more detailed in my question. In my case I’m looking for a vertical plane, that’s why I assumed that two points were enough. In that case how would I define the plane?